# How the check that I'm editing specific page Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In my app I'm editing a word document, I want to modify some values but I want the changes to affect **the first page, only**:

The content of the first page is like:

```
USER:
COMPANY:
```

and I want to modify it to:

```
USER: aaa
COMPANY: bbb
```

I have tried like:

```
//properties
object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object objEndOfDocFlag = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */ //Start Word and create a new document.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application objApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objDoc;



//load the document:
 objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\BugsFixer\file.docx", ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss, ref objMiss);

int count = objDoc.Words.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{                   
    string text = objDoc.Words[i].Text;
    if (text.StartsWith("USER"))
         objDoc.Words[i].Text = "USER: aaa";
    if (text.StartsWith("COMPANY"))
         objDoc.Words[i].Text = "COMPANY: bbb";                  
 }
```

but this woud change all "USER" strings. I need something like:

```
if(current page is one)
{
//replace USER with USER:aaa
//replace COMPANY with COMPANY:bbb
}
```

How to check that I'm editing a specific page i.e in my case page 1?

Comment: This may help you to select the first page: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3dff79f1-0f94-4525-8db8-a6d6d660fa03/get-specific-page-from-word-in-cnet-?forum=worddev

Comment: if possible, use form fields or named bookmarks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26409033/1132334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word has an interesting method: `get_Information` which takes an argument of the enumeration `Word.WdInformation`. There are a number of useful things this can return, among them, the current page number of a selection or Range.

Since the `Word` object returns a `Range` it's possible to query the page number something like this:

```
Word.Range rngWord = objDoc.Words[i];
string text = rngWord.Text;
int pgNumber = rngWord.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndPageNumber);
if (pgNumber = 1)
{
      if (text.StartsWith("USER"))
      { //and so on
```

Note that it's also possible to use `foreach` with the `Words` collection instead of getting the count of Words in the document and using a `for` loop.

All that being said, the code would probably be more efficient if it used Word's `Find` functionality instead of looping word-by-word...